# Arithmetic function & products

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how would you prove that $$ \prod_{d|n}d = n^{\tau(n)/2} $$
knowing that $ n= \prod_{i=1}^{r} P_{i}^{e_i}$ and that $\tau(n)= (e_1+1)(e_2+1)...(e_r+1) $

I have trying writing both sides in their multiplicative form, but it has not helped me proving the theorem. 
Help, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\tau(n)$ is the number of distinct divisors of $n$, you have
$$n^{\tau(n)} = \prod_{d|n} n = \prod_{d|n} d \cdot \frac{n}{d} = \left( \prod_{d|n} d \right) \cdot \left( \prod_{d|n} \frac{n}{d} \right) =
\left( \prod_{d|n} d \right)^2$$
which is equivalent to your statement.

Comment: thanks @Crostul ! helps a lot